# Is there an alternative to Softaculous AMPPS?

Tags: software-recommendation

Is an alternative to software stacks like AMPPS I can install web apps in one click on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

[AMPPS](http://www.ampps.com/download) is available for Ubuntu

Download the Linux version. Works like a charm.

Also, according to their blog, Webuzo supports Ubuntu. I haven't tested it myself though.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux. Softaculous has Webuzo. It doesn't support ubuntu yet. But it can be installed on CentOS. Here is the [requirement](http://www.webuzo.com/wiki/Install#Requirements)

If you don't have CentOS machine. You can directly download [Webuzo Virtual Machine](http://webuzo.com/download), select Installer Type **VMX**

Answer (score 0):

For web apps installation in one click you can use Deploy4Me. Is supports Ubuntu and AMPPS in various configurations. The good thing about Deploy4Me that there are a fully customizable server configuration available using visual editor; no vendor lock and pricing are very attractive.

If you need other software or cloud Deploy4Me have a ticket tracker for such requests. The service is growing very fast.